# SQL select command only returns column names

Tags: java, mysql, sql

When using the select query in Java JDBC on MySQL, it seems to only return the column's names and not the values associated with them. Like for instance, the following method returns `Content` even though that's the name of the column and not the value of it.

```
public <T> T select(String column, @Nullable List<DBCondition> conditions) {
    try (Statement statement = MySQL.createStatement()) {
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select '" + column + "' from " + name + (conditions == null || conditions.isEmpty() ? "" : " " + MySQL.conditionsListToString(conditions)) + ";");
        rs.next();
        return (T) rs.getObject(column);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

While debugging the created query ended up being `select Content from testtable where Name='Main_test';` which returns Content and not `{"Test":"Workss"}` as expected. This is expected because running the exact same query in the MySQL 'debugger' returns

```
+-------------------+
| Content           |
+-------------------+
| {"Test":"Workss"} |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: `"select '" + column + "' from "` selects a string constant, it should be `"select \`" + column + "\` from " `

Comment: The whole executeQuery line is a really good example on how NOT to use JDBC...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Alex K. for posting the correct answer, I had already figured my problem was quite had quite an obvious fix which it did. The fix was to not put the column in quotes, but rather in graves, so instead of doing `"select '" + column + "' from "` I should instead have done `"select`" + column + "`from "` but not putting the column in anything will also work.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use '. Use `" + column + "`

Comment: Well that worked, but I am gonna go with what Alex K. said with the graves since that seems safer and a better practice.